# Temporarily stop Qt5/QML from updating framebuffer (/dev/fb0)

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, qml, framebuffer

On an embedded system, due to very specific hardware/software limitations, we need another program to be able to display info via the framebuffer (/dev/fb0), while keeping our Qt5/QML program running in the background.
 We display a custom QQuickItem derived black rectangle (with nothing but a 'return' in the update()) in QML while the second program runs, but we still see flickering on our LCD display. 
 We surmise that QT is still painting the Screen Graph (possibly of other items layered beneath the rectangle) to /dev/fb0, thus causing flickering by both programs writing to /dev/fb0 at the same time.
We cannot use a second framebuffer approach (/dev/fb1) because the compositing increases processor loads dramatically such that the system becomes unusable.
 One thought is iterate through screen graph tree, marking all nodes 'ItemHasContents' flag as false so the screen graph renderer will not write to FB, then re-enable when the secondary program finishes its task.
 Another thought is to turn off rendering via the top level QWindow, but nothing in the documentation says this is even possible...
 Is this possible via QT, or even though a shell script?

Comment: Have you tried calling `setVisible(false)` on the top level QWindow?

Comment: Perhaps it is worth investigating whether making a long blocking function call from the UI thread will stop the application from writing to the frame buffer. Something like using select() to block watching stdin for the required number of ms, before timing out and continuing. Sorry I can't try it, I have no devices using qt direct to the fb

Comment: Or have the second process pause the Qt app using `kill -STOP` and `kill -CONT`. It sounds a bit dangerous though, if the Qt app was half way through an IO access. Obviously neither of these are acceptable if the Qt app needs to keep up any real-time activities during this interval

Comment: Is it possible to temporarily have the Qt app write to an offscreen frame buffer, using setRenderTarget()

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/fb0` sounds like you'd be working on a Linux-based system.

You're not saying whether you need the Qt application really continuing to run, just without screen updates, or whether simply "freezing" it while your other app uses the frame buffer would suffice.

If you are fine with the latter, the easiest solution to stop the Qt app from rendering is simply send it a SIGSTOP signal, it will freeze and cease to upgrade the frame buffer. Once you're done with the fb, send a SIGCONT signal. Sometimes the simplest approaches are the best...

Comment: We actually need it to run, which is why we're trying to avoid the SIGSTOP?SIGCONT route. We've got some comm threads that keep things alive in the back ground and they need to meet some critical timing requirements.

Comment: @tofro Could you please tell me how to proceed with the former requirement? I mean I have 2 QT apps, 1 is running using XCB plugin(uses DRM/KMS) and the other uses the Framebuffer. When I switch to the framebuffer QT app by doing chvt it works. But I cannot go back to the QT XCB app by doing chvt 1. Any suggestions on how to run both apps in parallel in different ttys and swtiching back and forth?